# AndEngine menu item with labels

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, andengine

I am new to AndEngine programming but I have a bit of experience in Cocos2D. Is there any way to create a menu item without a sprite but through a label like the CCMenuItemLabel of Cocos2D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to implement 
**IOnMenuItemClickListener**

interface and override the method

> onMenuItemClicked

After that you can create menu items as follows:

```
TextMenuItem playText = new TextMenuItem(menuItemId,
                    menuFont, "TEXT_TO_DISPLAY",vbom);
object.addMenuItem(playText);
```

Then you may add this menu item on the Object which has implemented **IOnMenuItemClickListener**.

Comment: what's the object to which I can add a menu item? (i.e. onject.addMenuItem)

Comment: suppose I have a scene implementing the IonMenuItemClickListener it doesn't have the addMenuItem anyway

Comment: You have to use MenuScene class from andengine itself, and then add menuItem on the MenuScene object. Then call object.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this); from the class which implements IOnMenuItemClickListener (in your case a scene). Add handle events on OnMenuItemClicked method from the listener inherited into your scene class.